# Ignoring long running threads in New Relic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, newrelic

I have a long running database import on a web application which massively skews my charts on New Relic.

On the controller I am calling `NewRelic.IgnoreTransaction()` but still seeing a huge spike on time spent in the database.

The actual import itself is done on a separate thread and wrapped in a transaction and I'm wondering if this is the reason. Do I need to call `IgnoreTransaction` again either within the transaction or the thread or is it simply not possible to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work for New Relic,

You're correct with your assumption about calling it again.
You will need to call `NewRelic.IgnoreTransaction()` in both threads for this to work properly.

The IgnoreTransaction method doesn't ignore transactions that are wrapped in a controller, just the controller itself.